# How to create a jagged string array in c++?

Tags: c++, jagged-arrays

I want to create jagged character two dimensional array in c++.

```
int arrsize[3] = {10, 5, 2};
char** record;
record = (char**)malloc(3);
cout << endl << sizeof(record) << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
    record[i] = (char *)malloc(arrsize[i] * sizeof(char *));
    cout << endl << sizeof(record[i]) << endl;
}
```

I want to set `record[0]` for name (should have 10 letter), `record[1]` for marks (should have 5 digit mark )and `record[3]` for Id (should have 2 digit number). How can i implement this? I directly write the record array to the binary file. I don't want to use `struct` and `class`.

Comment: Is this C or C++? It really matters.

Comment: As you are using C++ use std::vector and std::string.

Comment: If the entries in the `record` array are strings, remember that you need space for the string terminator character, or use `memcpy` or `strncpy` instead of simple `strcpy`.

Answer (score 5):

in C++ it would like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> record;
```

Comment: You probably skipped over the part where the question ask for a solution that can be directly written to a binary file. This has the same problem as the original question's code: memory is non-contiguous and cannot be written in a single `write`.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you not use a struct when it is the sensible solution to your problem?

```
struct record {
   char name[10];
   char mark[5];
   char id[2];
};
```

Then writing to a binary file becomes trivial:

```
record r = get_a_record();
write( fd, &r, sizeof r );
```

Notes:

- You might want to allocate a bit of extra space for NUL terminators, but this depends on the format that you want to use in the file.
- If you are writing to a binary file, why do you want to write `mark` and `id` as strings? Why not store an `int` (4 bytes, greater range of values) and a `unsigned char` (1 byte)

If you insist on not using a user defined type (really, you should), then you can just create a single block of memory and use pointer arithmetic, but beware that the binary generated by the compiler will be the same, the only difference is that your code will be less maintainable:

```
char record[ 10+5+2 ];
// copy name to record
// copy mark to record+10
// copy id to record+15
write( fd, record, sizeof record);
```

Comment: Does the language guarantee that these arrays will occupy contiguous memory? I mean, couldn't the compiler add some padding between them for efficiency reasons? Just asking, I really don't know the answer.

Comment: @Gorpik: `char` has no alignment restrictions, so there would be no reason to pad in any architecture. The standard allows internal padding for the purpose of alignment §9.2/14 or management of virtual functions or virtual base classes (not present in this type)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the right pattern “to malloc” is:

```
T * p = (T *) malloc(count * sizeof(T));
```

where `T` could be any type, including `char *`. So the right code for allocating memory in this case is like that:

```
int arrsize[3] = { 10, 5, 2 };
char** record;
record = (char**) malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
cout << sizeof(record) << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    record[i] = (char *) malloc(arrsize[i] * sizeof(char));
}
```

I deleted cout'ing `sizeof(record[i])` because it will always yield size of (one) pointer to char (4 on my laptop). sizeof is something that plays in compiling time and has no idea how much memory pointed by `record[i]` (which is really a pointer - `char *` type) was allocated in the execution time.

Comment: Though Anders K.'s advice for using vectors/strings in C++ is worth considering.

Comment: The *good* pattern in C is rather: `T * p = malloc( count * sizeof *p );` the difference being that you only need to update the type in one place if it changes. In C++ an extra cast would have to be added on the result of malloc, but still the compiler will tell you that, while it will not tell you that you forgot to update the size that is requested.

Comment: This answer also fails to deal with the problem of writing to a file. It basically leaves the code as it was and provides no advantage.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc(3)` allocates 3 bytes. Your jagged array would be an array containing pointers to character arrays. Each pointer usually takes 4 bytes (on a 32-bit machine), but more correctly `sizeof(char*)`, so you should allocate using `malloc(3 * sizeof(char*) )`.

And then `record[i] = (char*)malloc((arrsize[i]+1) * sizeof(char))`, because a string is a `char*` and a character is a `char`, and because each C-style string is conventionally terminated with a `'\0'` character to indicate its length. You could do without it, but it would be harder to use for instance:

```
strcpy(record[0], name);
sprintf(record[1], "%0.2f", mark);
sprintf(record[2], "%d", id);
```

to fill in your record, because `sprintf` puts in a `\0` at the end. I assumed `mark` was a floating-point number and `id` was an integer.

As regards writing all this to a file, if the file is binary why put everything in as strings in the first place?
Assuming you do, you could use something like:

```
ofstream f("myfile",ios_base::out|ios_base::binary);
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    f.write(record[i], arrsize[i]);
f.close();
```

That being said, I second Anders' idea. If you use STL vectors and strings, you won't have to deal with ugly memory allocations, and your code will probably look cleaner as well.

Comment: Again, this fails to resolve the issue of writing to a binary file.

Comment: If we're being particularly pedantic, the file is stored on disk in binary form, and I've provided code to write binary data under some encoding to said file, therefore resolving the issue of writing to a binary file. In any case, the OP said he was directly writing the record array to the file. He never mentioned a conversion. If anything, I'd assume he's converting primitive types to strings, for writing.

Comment: I guess I should have been more precise on what I meant: this has the same problem as the original code, the fields are not stored contiguously in memory which means that it cannot be read/written in a single call to read/write. All the solutions based on the original approach of a *jagged* array suffer that same problem, unless the *jagged* array is implemented as a linear array and pointer arithmetic to obtain the beginning of each field.